# Doxygen error: Failed to open temporary file /path/to/file/doxygen_objdb_3332.tmp

Tags: c++, doxygen

i'm trying to generate uml graph from c++ codes. after i've changed the following lines like below
 `EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
    HAVE_DOT               = YES
    UML_LOOK               = YES`

then i'm getting then this error message 
```

> doxygen 
>   error: Failed to open temporary file /path/to/file/doxygen_objdb_3332.tmp```

does anyone know how to solve this. I'm using doxygen 1.8.11 on OSX 10.10. Thanks!

**Solved**: The c++ codes were in **dropbox**, i've ***moved*** to my user folder from dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

This error can appear if doxygen doesn't have write access to the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I had a similar problem generating NED files, and full C++ documentation using the OMNET++ documentation generator.

OMNET++ comes with Doxygen, but it turned out that the version was out of date. I ended up downloading the newest version of Doxygen, and replacing the existing doxygen.exe file with the most up-to-date version (at the time of this post, it was found here: http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html)

I hope this helps any future users out! It took me quite a while to figure out.

Regards,

Van